# HTML java data binding

Tags: java, html, data-binding

Is there any framework for HTML Java data binding? I found on google that asp.net supports it. Do we have anything similar in java?

A quick googling found me this: http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/index.html

Is there enything else like this?

Comment: Almost every java web framework has binding options.

Comment: With HTML? I don't think so..

Comment: Any more answer? Please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i remember SpringMVC has data binding capabilities for form backing objects.
Jersey, the reference implementation of JSR-311 also does automatic data binding for your resource objects.

checkout http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

and: http://jersey.java.net/